# eBay mobile website on Ubuntu no longer supported

Tags: webapps

How do I update the eBay app on my Ubuntu tablet?
Message says The eBay mobile website is no longer supported on this device

Answer (score 1):

Try it again now. I had this issue before but for the last week or so I have been able to view ebay on both the default browser and the ebay app.

Comment: Well! What do you know! It works and is well-optimised for Android phone and tablet.  Many thanks for letting us know.